# Trying to parse JSON data, but it is coming back as undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse an object with several arrays, and within the chosen array, console.log() an object.

So far my javascript looks like this:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',loadObject);

function loadObject(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('GET', 'objects.json', true);

    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(this.status == 200){
            var objects = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(objects.records[2].object_number);
        }
    }

    xhr.send();
}
```

When I click the button, it returns undefined. However, if I console.log(objects.records[2]); it returns the correct array. I am new to javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: More infos would be great! And why don't you use `objects.records[2][x]` with x = array position of object_number field

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys! I realised I read the JSON data wrong. Turns out I had to access another object. So now my code looks like this and it works!

`console.log(objects.records[2].fields.object_number);`